# XAgent to Export to Excel

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Have an issue when exporting data out via an XPage XAgent. All works fine in IE and Firefox, but Chrome doesn't recognise it as an Excel spreadsheet, downloads and saves it as the name of the XPage (report.xsp).. Just doing simple stuff..

```
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = xxCon.getResponse();response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
writer.write("<table border=\"1\">");
writer.write("<thead><tr>");
etc...
```

Am I missing something, or is there a better way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Disposition header that tells the browser the name of the file?

Comment: Hi Per... thanks I added response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=CompareABull.xlsx") now Excel refuses to open the file

Comment: So Chrome downloads the file as expected now? What does Excel say?

Comment: Hi Per, Excel says 'Excel cannot open the file 'CompareABull.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file' with an Ok button and doesn't open.

Comment: I changed the extension from .xlsx to .xls seems to be working ok now. Thanks Per for the session about content-disposition looks like it's done the job.

Comment: Great to hear. I added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Content-Disposition header that tells the browser the name of the file.

Here's an example:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=filename.xls"
```